# Changing .css property through external Javascript on Adobe Edge?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, adobe-edge

I'm trying to create all kinds of functions on an external .js file, so I can just call them in Edge multiple times with less coding. The thing is, after importing jQuery and my external Javascript file, some code works, but I get stuck at this part: changing the .css property of a symbol, more specifically, the "font-size" property. My current function is:

```
function setFont(textid,fontsize,originalWinWidth){ 
//textid: symbol's name; fontsize: current font size of this symbol; originalWinWidth:
//window size at the start of the animation

console.log("Set Font:");

//set the original font size
var originalFontSize = Math.round(originalWinWidth/fontsize);
console.log("Original Font Size: " + originalFontSize);
console.log("Text ID: " + textid);

//set the font size using jquery
sym.$(textid).css("font-size", originalFontSize);  
}
```

I get the error "Javascript error in event handler! Event Type = element" at the last line, all other parts of the code works. Any idea what this could be?

Thanks,

Rafael Carignato

Comment: `sym.$("#"+textid).css("font-size", originalFontSize);` ?

Comment: No, this doesn't work.